# Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы повторяющиеся элементы не добавлялись в новый список

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, циклы

```
def enumeration(data, starter):
    lister = []
    for element in data:
        if element in lister:
            pass
        else:
            lister.append((element, starter))
            starter += 1
    return lister
list1 = [5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1]
list2 = enumeration(list1, 1)
print(list2)
```

Вот я хочу сделать так, чтобы, если элемент в старом списке повторяется, то в новый список он не заносится, и счетчик не инкрементируется. То есть я хотел, чтобы в исходном коде программа выдала:
[(5, 1), (4, 2), (3, 3), (2, 4), (1, 5)]. Но он выдает:
[(5, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (2, 6), (1, 7)], хотя в программе я вроде написал, что, если элемент повторяется, то добавлять его не надо и счетчик не инкрементировать. Я думаю, что ошибка скорее всего в том, что в новом списке нет именно одиночного элемента, а есть пара - (элемент, номер), и поскольку пара (элемент, номер) никогда не повторится, так как счетчик инкрементируется, то в новый список добавляется все. Но как тогда сделать, чтобы программа распознавала в этой паре именно элемент и не добавляла бы элемент с тем же значением?

P.S И объясните, пожалуйста, почему у нас список состоит именно из tuple, а не, например, список из списков. Заранее спасибо.

P.P.S Я знаю, что в питоне есть функция enumerate, просто хочется попробовать самому написать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас список содержит кортежи

```
lister.append((element, starter))
```

а вы поиск делаете по элементу кортежа -

```
if element in lister
```

это так не работа

Вариантов решения задачи много, например можно использовать множество для индикатора того, что элемент уже использован:

```
def enumeration(data, starter):
    unique = set()

    lister = []

    for element in data:
        if element not in unique:
            unique.add(element)
            lister.append((element, starter))
            starter += 1
    return lister

list1 = [5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1]
list2 = enumeration(list1, 1)
print(list2)
```

Можно обойтись без `set`:

```
def enumeration(data, starter):
    lister = []

    for element in data:
        if element not in lister:
            lister.append(element)

    lister = [(i[1], starter + i[0]) for i in enumerate(lister)]

    return lister
```

А можно немного извратиться:

```
def enumeration(data, starter):
    lister = []

    for element in data:
        if len(list(filter(lambda i: i[0] == element, lister))) == 0:
            lister.append((element, starter + len(lister)))

    return lister
```

Comment: А почему эти пары элементов выводятся как tuple? Я же вроде нигде не писал то, чтобы он выводил эти пары типом tuple.

Comment: @prostak вы же делаете `lister.append((element, starter))` - т.е. вы добавляете кортеж `(element, starter)`